# Finding number of graphics cards in red hat weird error

Tags: ruby, split

So I know how to find the number of the video cards but in a ruby script I wrote I had this small little method to determine it:

```
def getNumCards
    _numGpu = %x{lspci | grep VGA}.split("\n").size
end
```

But have determined I need to do a search for 3D as well as VGA so I changed it to:

```
def getNumCards
    _numGpu = %x{lspci | grep "VGA\|3D"}.split("\n").size
end
```

But I am finding it returns 0 when I run the second. If I run the command on it's own on the command line, it shows me 3 video cards (1 on board VGA and two Tesla NVIDIA cards that come up as 3D cards). I am not sure what is happening in the split part that may be messing something up.

Any help would be awesome!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

man grep:

```
-E, --extended-regexp
...
egrep is the same as grep -E.
```

so, `egrep` should help

Answer (score 0):

I'd go after this information one of two ways.

The almost-purely command-line version would be:

```
def getNumCards
  `lspci | grep -P '\b(?:VGA|3D)\b' | wc -l`.to_i
end
```

which lets the OS do almost all the work, except for the final conversion to an integer.

`-P '\b(?:VGA|3D)\b'` is a Perl regex that says "find a word-break, then look for VGA or 3D, followed by another word-break". That'll help avoid any hits due to the targets being embedded in other strings.

The more-Ruby version would be:

```
def getNumCards
  `lspci`.split("\n").grep(/\b(?:VGA|3D)\b/).count
end
```

It does the same thing, only all in Ruby.